# excel: clearing values out of pasted cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a worksheet that contains a row which I am happy with, including formatting and function processing.
I have duplicated that particular row to the other rows in the sheet, and now I would like to "zero out" or create null values for the duped cells.

I attempted to "clear contents", but that also clears the formatting that I had set.
How do most people do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does <kbd>DEL</kbd> not work?  Deleting the cells should keep the format but remove the contents.

Comment: DEL deletes a single cell, and if i choose "delete...", i get options to remove the cells and shift up/down etc.  Which is not what I want.  I would like to clear the cell data but keep the formatting.

Comment: DEL deletes the contents of all cells in the current selection. Select all the cells you want to clear before pressing DEL. You can select multiple cells by left-click and dragging or holding Shift down while pressing the arrow keys.

Comment: i should have mentioned this before, but i am on a mac.  i didn't realize that i needed to use the separate delete key for the deletion.  thank you.